# How to keep business rule in case of two different aggregates?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a some domain modeling case: There is two domain concepts Worksite and Contract. Every Contract belongs to some Worksite. I've already found out that both concepts are own aggregates but there is still business rule that the validity period of Contract must always be inside the duration period of Worksite. So how to keep that consistency true?

Okay, when I create a new Contract I can do it as follows:

```
public class Worksite {

   private Period period;            

   public Contract createContract( Period period, ... ) {

     if ( !this.period.inside( period ) ) ) {
       throw new SomeException();
     } 

     ...

     return new Contract( new ContractId( .. ), this.id(), period, ... );

  }    

}
```

but what can I do, when someone modifies Worksites' or Contract's period afterwards? Both have different consistency boundary so I can't do it in same transaction.. or is this the case when I need to break the rule?

Comment: So, it is fixed that they are two separate aggregates, right?

Comment: What happens with the contracts when the worksite has its period reduced?

Answer (score 1):

**You should not break the rule if that's what the business needs.**

Considering that there are two separate aggregates then **eventual consistency** must come into play.

So, what happens when somebody modifies the period of a contract? We must ensure that the period is still inside the Worksite, but that information is inside other aggregate.

The solution is that, when someone tries to modify the period of a contract we start a process of verification and only after the process is finished we actually change the contract's period.

We do this by puting the `aggregate` in a special state named for example `period_verification_started`, without changing the old period. Then we start a `Saga`/`Process manager` that loads the `Worksite` from `repository`, it gets its period then it forwards it to the `Contract aggregate`. The `Contract aggregate` checks the invariant then it changes the period or rejects the change request by setting its status accordingly.

On the other side, if a `Worksite` needs to change its period, then the same strategy could be employed by starting a `Saga` that loads all the relevant `Contracts` from repository and if the invariant holds only then the period is "commited".

If an `Event-driven architecture` is used all this is done simpler by the `Sagas` listening to the relevant `events` and by sending `commands` to the two `Aggregates`.

Answer (score 1):

So caution number one -- carving up your model into aggregates is an optimization.  Aggregates doesn't make the model more correct.  What they do is reduce the amount of state that the model needs to consider in any given change, and they give you the option of making concurrent changes to unrelated bits of state.

> Every Contract belongs to some Worksite.

That suggests that the contract entities and the related worksite entity could be part of the same aggregate.  That should be the first avenue you explore: what's the cost of keeping the related state together?

Second thing to be sure to understand: is the model the authority that decides this information, or is the model just checking that consistent decisions have been made elsewhere (or that data entry has been done correctly).

If contracts and worksite periods are determined outside the model, then the model probably shouldn't be rejecting the changes.  Who are you going to believe, the model or the ink on the contract?

Greg Young had an interesting suggestion in this space: [stop over engineering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRr4xeMn1uU).  In many cases, you can get a lot of business value from having the solution detect inconsistencies and escalate them to a human being, rather tha trying to immediately resolve them in code.  What's the cost/benefit of doing the extra work to get immediately consistent results, rather than a correction after escalation?

On the other hand, if the model really is the authority for deciding where the periods are, then you definitely want both periods in the same aggregate, and you should be reviewing the domain model to make sure you really understand where that data belongs.

(Side hint: aggregates are information, not physical things.  You may want to explore the ubiquitous language of your domain to see if "worksite" is the right noun to have in your model; where does the period of the worksite come from?)